# Error with an api route - Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to access to this route: http://anaketesting.tk/product-service/payment-notification Really is a route for api, but consuming the route, have same error that browser.
**My route try 1:**

```
Route::get('/product-service/payment-notification', "ProductServiceController@notification")->name('productService.notification');
```

**My route try 2:**

```
Route::get('/product-service/payment-notification', function(){
    return \Response::json([
      'CREATED' => true
    ], 201); #also i tryed return 201 directly...
});
```

**My route try 3:**

```
Route::get('product-service/payment-notification', [
    'as'   => 'productService.notification',
    'uses' => 'ProductServiceController@notification'
]);
```

**My notification méthod**

```
public function notification(Request $request){
$date = Carbon::now();
$date = $date->format('Ymdhis');
file_put_contents(storage_path().'/notification_'.$date.'.json', \Response::json($request));

    return \Response::json([
      'CREATED' => true
    ], 201);
 }
```

I have not an storage/logs error with this method, is as was ignored. Please help ;)

Comment: Another routes run fine*

Comment: Didn't you wrap this route (and maybe some other) in a route group with prefix?

What the error says?

Comment: No i didn't, is a simple route. {"error":"Something went wrong","message":""}
This is the error message. But Laravel isn't writing the log for this route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see the [RouteServiceProvider](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.3.0/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php) of Laravel 5.3, it shows that api routes being grouped and prefixed with **api** by default.

/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php

```
/**
 * Define the "api" routes for the application.
 *
 * These routes are typically stateless.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'api',
        'namespace' => $this->namespace,
        'prefix' => 'api',
    ], function ($router) {
        require base_path('routes/api.php');
    });
}
```

So you need to prefix api in your url. for example

to call this route

```
Route::get('/product-service/payment-notification', "ProductServiceController@notification")->name('productService.notification');
```

you need to call

[http://anaketesting.tk/api/product-service/payment-notification](http://so%20you%20need%20to%20prefix%20api%20in%20your%20url.%20for%20example%20%20to%20call%20this%20route%20%20%20%20%20%20Route::get('/product-service/payment-notification',%20%22ProductServiceController@notification%22)-%3Ename('productService.notification');%20%20%20you%20need%20to%20call%20%20%20http://anaketesting.tk/api/product-service/payment-notification%20%20not%20%20%20http://anaketesting.tk/product-service/payment-notification)

not

http://anaketesting.tk/product-service/payment-notification

Answer (score 0):

in TRY3, as your system is skipping some logs, there might be two different issues

1. Your system doesn't have sufficient permission to write data into log files. in order to use this, you have to give permission to your log files.
2. You can handle these types of exceptions by using CustomException,

go to App/Exceptions/Handler.php

```php
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        if($exception instanceof  RouteNotFoundException){
            abort(404,'Invalid Route Requested');
        }else{
            return parent::render($request, $exception);
        }
    }
```